# Regular Expression for getting last string after last slash and replace first two letters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string `ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234` Now, I only want to get TT1234 and replace TT with YY.

Input: `ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234`
Output: `YY1234`

I have an expression to get the last part `([^|]+$)`, but not sure what to do next.

Comment: Try `var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"^.*\|TT([^|]*)$", "YY$1")`

Comment: This may be over-complicated. If you know the specific index positions of the TT in the string beforehand (possibly from the end) you may not even need to use RegEx. Is your input always in a specific, predictable, non user-submitted format?

Comment: Off-topic: there are no slashes in your string, but there are _pipes_.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the problem is best solved with regex, or if this regex will work with all your inputs but In C# you can use `Regex.Replace`.

```
        var input = "ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234";

        var reg = "([A-Z]{2})(?=[^|]+$)";

        var output = Regex.Replace(input, reg, "YY");

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

explanation of the regex -

`([A-Z]{2})` find any two capital letters

`(?=[^|]+$)` negative look ahead of not a | and end of line. We use a negative look ahead so this bit doesn't get captured

Answer (score 0):

RegEx is usefull to find your important parts, but replacing is a different thing, you tagged this question with `c#` tag, so, I think this can help you (I'm using Regex.Replace, but a simple replace will do the work):

```
        string input = "ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234";

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^|]+$)");
        Match match = regex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            //replace
            string output = Regex.Replace(match.Value, "TT", "YY");

            Console.WriteLine(output);
        }

        Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex in C#

```
string input = "ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"([^|]+$)");
string result = regex.Replace("TT", "YY");
```

Think this is what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is build with | as divider, why use regex at all?

```
string input = "ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234";

var last = input.Split("|".ToCharArray()).Last()
var done = last.Replace("TT","YY");
```

(VS updating, can`t verify syntax)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve this without regular expressions:

```
string input = "ABC|DEF|XYZ|TT1234";
string output = "YY" + input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("TT") + 2);
```

Or if the last characters can contain letters:

```
string output = "YY" + input.Substring(input.LastIndexOf("|TT") + 3);
```